# What is the state of a baby who dies in the womb in the hereafter?

Tags: jannah, death, jahannam, baby

What is the state of a baby who dies in the womb in the hereafter?
Will it go to jannah or not?

Give answer according to islamic point of view!

Comment: [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25785/why-a-little-child-goes-directly-to-jannah) is somewhat relevant.